# PLW-07203: parameter may benefit from use of the NOCOPY compiler hint

Tags: oracle, plsql

I'm doing code cleanup and turned PL/SQL Warnings on by doing `ALTER SESSION SET PLSQL_WARNINGS='ENABLE:ALL';` to show the unused variables. I got the Warning 
`PLW-07203: parameter 'p_trans_no' may benefit from use of the NOCOPY compiler hint`

I'm curious, what exact benefit would the program get in terms of performance, standardization or simplicity if i put a `NOCOPY` hint?

This is my Procedure Signature:

```
PROCEDURE GET_ICT_ITEM_ATTR
(
    p_itemtype          IN  VARCHAR2
,   p_itemkey           IN  VARCHAR2
,   p_trans_no          OUT VARCHAR2
,   p_trans_date        OUT DATE
,   p_requestor         OUT VARCHAR2
,   p_appr1             OUT VARCHAR2
,   p_appr2             OUT VARCHAR2
,   p_bg_id             OUT NUMBER
);
```

Comment: Basically, `NOCOPY` is like pass by reference, default would be pass by value. Better explanation [here](http://www.dba-oracle.com/t_pl_sql_nocopy_data_structures.htm)

Comment: thank you @MaheswaranRavisankar from what i understand, `NOCOPY` is safe to use in `OUT` Parameters, but for `IN OUT` Parameters, there is a risk because runtime values will be "saved" if exceptions occur midway. is this correct?

Comment: Yes, you're right.

Comment: Just for sanity, your warning refers to a parameter `p_trx_no` which does not exist in the procedure definition you posted.  Either the warning is referring to a different parameter and you have a transcription error in putting the question together or it is referring to a different procedure.

Comment: hi @JustinCave, i made a typo. let me edit and correct it. thanks!

Comment: `nocopy` needs extra care in both cases 'out' and 'in out'. Any unexpected exit from subprogram may result in partially formed array for example. Without `nocopy` option you have to be careful only in exception handling block of your subprogram.

Comment: thanks for the tip @KonstantinSorokin. i'm currently not dealing with arrays as parameters, does this make it safe to use `NOCOPY`? thanks!

Comment: Array or not using `nocopy` increase probability of mistakes and needs extra care. See [Formal Parameter Declaration](https://docs.oracle.com/cloud/latest/db112/LNPLS/parameter_declaration.htm#LNPLS1271) and [Subprogram Parameter Aliasing with Parameters Passed by Reference](https://docs.oracle.com/cloud/latest/db112/LNPLS/subprograms.htm#CHDGBIEC)